# How to use Zeptos from Foundation 4 in Require.js and Grunt from Yeoman

Tags: jquery, requirejs, zurb-foundation, zepto

I just got Foundation 4 to function with Yeoman using Require.js. The gist I used for main.js in Require.js is here: https://gist.github.com/lkbgift/5164200

Foundation 4's index.html calls Zepto with this script:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

In require.js, you declare the jquery path like there:

```
paths: {
  jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery'
},
```

What is the proper way to integrate the zepto code?

ps: Best convoluted title ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using require I think it probably makes sense to load all your scripts with require, if only for consistency.

The Foundation 4 code you've posted loads Zepto for browsers which support the **proto** property and jQuery for others (essentially only IE according to [this page](http://corporate.tuenti.com/es/dev/blog/-mobile-libraries-that-worked-well-for-us-and-might-work-well-for-you-too)).

If you're happy to push out Zepto to everyone (maybe you don't need to support IE), you could just update the code you've posted from your require config to point to Zepto instead of jQuery. Alternatively you could push out jQuery to everyone. When I looked at Zepto, all be it briefly, it didn't really seem to offer a whole lot over jQuery (see performance tests [here](http://www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html)).

If you want to preserve the Foundation 4 logic in your require configuration, there's an example on [this require.js github issues page](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/451) which demonstrates how you would go about loading files conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

In your main.js function where you are configuring require, create a new function called isModern or something like that. Have this function return the result of the **proto** evaluation (bool). Something like this:

```
function isModern() { return ( __proto__ in {} ); }
```

In your paths config, change 'jquery' path config to 'libdom' or something like that. Configure libdom like this:

```
paths: {
    'libdom': (isModern()) ? 'your path to zepto' : ' your path to jquery'
},
```

...
...

Now, instead of passing 'jquery' into require({...});, you will pass 'libdom', which will either be Zepto or jQuery depending on the result of isModern.